# Specifying path to a file within a program command line

Tags: shell-script, path, pwd

I am using a program called Diamond and I have a script that goes like this:

```
cd /srv/scratch/myname/hello
diamond blastp -d /srv/scratch/myname/goodbye/inputFile1.dmnd -q inputFile2.faa -o /diamond/outputFile.txt
```

I have my `inputFile2.faa` in the working directory (`/srv/scratch/myname/hello`) and I have my other `inputFile1.dmnd` in another directory. As `inputFile1.dmnd` is a massive file and is being used in other command lines I do not want to move it to my current working directory as this would be impractical.

When I run this command line I get 'No such file or directory'. 
Is there a way to specify the absolute/relative path so I can keep my `inputFile1.dmnd` in a neutral directory?

I expect the answer to that question will help me with this one too but with my `outputFile.txt`.  I also want to specify which directory to put it in relative to my working directory; is there a way to do that?

Comment: What is the _full_ error message?

Comment: diamond v0.9.24.125 | by Benjamin Buchfink <buchfink@gmail.com>
Licensed under the GNU GPL <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt>
Check http://github.com/bbuchfink/diamond for updates.

#CPU threads: 16
Scoring parameters: (Matrix=BLOSUM62 Lambda=0.267 K=0.041 Penalties=11/1)
No such file or directory

Comment: Is both the files `/srv/scratch/myname/goodbye/inputFile1.dmnd`, `/srv/scratch/myname/hello/inputFile2.faa`, and the directory `/diamond` available (are you able to `ls` them)?  Are you running this as a job on a cluster with something like Slurm? If so, are the file and directory available on the compute node running the job?

Comment: Are you sure the error is not about inputFile2.faa?

Comment: Yep, I can ls both. Yes, it is being run on a cluster with a job scheduler. The files and directories are no less available than any others like the directory I cd'd to. I thought I might have simply not known how to do this but it looks like it's shaping up to be something I might talk to our HPC IT people about.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are the real paths, the problem is most likely the character `#`.

Options:

1) Don't use `#` in file or directories names, if you can avoid it. So rename `/srv/scratch/#` to something else, like `/srv/scratch/hash`. You'll need escaping (see below) to do this.

2) Escape `#` with a backslash:

```
diamond blastp -d /srv/scratch/\#/goodbye/inputFile1.dmnd -q inputFile2.faa -o /diamond/outputFile.txt
```

3) Escape the complete filename with single quotes:

```
diamond blastp -d '/srv/scratch/#/goodbye/inputFile1.dmnd' -q inputFile2.faa -o /diamond/outputFile.txt
```

You can test all this by using a standard command like `ls` together with the filename, and optional bash tab completion (which will add escaping).

Comment: `bash` (for example) would have no issue with `#` when specified as part of a pathname like what the user is doing.

Comment: I am using bash. I'm terribly sorry, I should have clarified, the # is just my name on my university's computer that I replaced to hide my identity.